# Repairing yum's repositories on a RHEL5

Tags: linux, yum, rhel5, rpm

I am using RHEL5 and yum is missing many packages,  such as apache, php, and all php libraries .  I have added the rpmforge repository,  but i am still missing these packages.  This is an i686 machine and there might not be many i686 packages available, I think that if i force an i386 i'll have serious problems.

How do I make sure I have a large number of compatible packages on a RHEL5 system?  I didn't install this system,  is it normal for RHEL5 to have virtually no useful packages in yum?  How do RHEL5 administrators use yum without introducing conflicts with currently installed packages?  Should I ditch yum and use apt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have one or more of the main Red Hat repositories disabled.  Have a look at the files in /etc/yum.repos.d and make sure that:

1. The Red Hat .repo files are there
2. The repository definitions inside the .repo files are not set to "enabled=0"

Also, check any errors that you get when you try to run yum - it's possible that you can;t get to the repository URL defined in the .repo file from your machine.

Comment: Your right,  i am missing the redhat repo!  How do I re-add it?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a Red Hat machine handy to check; the best I can suggest is to look at another RHEL5 machine if you have one, or search the redhat.com knowledge base.

Comment: In RHEL-5 the red hat repos. are automatically added by "rhnplugin", assuming the machine is subscribed.

Answer (score 1):

ehm, your RHEL5 machine is suscribed to RedHat Network ?

i presume that the people that installa RHEL in this machine, dont suscribe this one to RedHat Network to have access to the Repositories for install/update.

if you pay for this the suscription cost, go to the people that did the install service and demand that complete the install (the suscription part)

if you dont pay, you need to pay for suscription, or reinstall using a RHEL clone like CentOS

Comment: Yeah i have come to the conclusion that YUM is complete garbage and i'll avoid RHEL as much as i can.  as for CentOS,  i think that project is dead,  they haven't released an update in a few years.